# Lazy loaded property readability

Tags: c#, lazy

I currently have code that looks like this

```
private string _stringField;

protected string StringField
{
    get
    {
        if (_stringField == null)
            _stringField = GetStringField();
        return _stringField;
    }
}
```

ReSharper is suggesting I change the property to:

```
protected string StringField
{
    get
    {
        return _stringField ?? (_stringField = GetStringField());
    }
}
```

This isn't an idiom I've seen before and probably would have to think about the first time I saw it; is this something I should be concerned would confuse other people too?

Comment: That and using Lazy<> is how I tend to do my properties when wanting something like this.  Just seems more consise to me.  As for confusing others?  Possibly but it might also teach them something...

Comment: @dreza Thanks for pointing out Lazy<>; most of my C# work has been with 3.5 or earlier and this is the first I've seen it.

Comment: Even with `Lazy<T>`, I still tend to use this approach in most cases. Choose whichever feels simpler to you and don't worry about confusing other people. I totally agree with @dreza here: That piece of code is clear enough for someone who saw something like that for the first time to _get it_ in one minute.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is well known operator in C#.  It doesn't confuse but reduce coding.

Both snippets have same meaning.

But if it is .NET 4.0 onwards, i would rather use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx).

```
private Lazy<string> lazyStringField = new Lazy<string>(GetStringField);
protected string StringField
{
    get
    {
        return lazyStringField.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of the ?? operator; what I've never seen before was it being glued together with an assignment statement like that before.

Comment: How much slower is this code?

Comment: While I'd agree that normally `??` doesn't confuse, I'd argue that it's usage here combined with the rarely-used side effect of `=` which returns the value just set *is* confusing.

Comment: lazy properties are not supported in CF and should be implemented manually

Answer (score 7):

I noticed that ReSharper's suggestion too and I decided to turn it off. I think that an expression should be used either for its value or for its side-effects, *but not both*. If you do both, your code will be more confusing. This principle is known as [command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation).

And I agree with others that using `Lazy<T>` is even better. If you're still on .Net 3.5 (or older), [it shouldn't be that hard to write your own version of that class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3207580/41071).

Comment: I've turned off that suggestion as well.  Sometimes ReSharper's suggestions make the code less intuitive...